# When to use an adjustment method for Kruskal-Wallis + Dunn's and which method?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, kruskal-wallis-test, bonferroni, adjustment, dunn-test

I need to do multiple pairwise comparisons among 5 groups (Treatment 1, Treatment 2, Treatment 3, Positive Control, Negative Control) for different tests and times. Each group has $10$ individuals, except for the negative control ($n=5$).

In most of the tests/times, the positive and negative control are all zero. The data are not normally distributed within each group, so I have done Kruskal-Wallis and Dunn's test in R, with and without adopting an adjustment method (Bonferroni). The results using the Bonferroni adjustment are a little bit weird, probably because of the different size of the negative control group. In fact, although both controls are zero, often the treatment groups are different from the positive control, but not with the negative control thing that doesn't happen without using an adjustment method.
Can someone help me to understand if I really need to adjust Dunn's test, and if that is the case, which method could be better for my dataset?